# Изменение innerHTML при клике на ссылку

Tags: javascript, html

```
<a href="#" onclick="this.innerHTML = *"> Контакты</a>
```

Если вместо `*` стоят цифры, то всё работает. Если текст, то не работает. Почему?

Пример неработающего кода:

```
<a href="#" onclick="this.innerHTML = текст"> Контакты</a>
```

Comment: если *не читается*, видимо, проблема с кодировками сайта и файла

Comment: <a href="#" onclick="this.
innerHTML = текст"> Контакты</a>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Строка *текст* должна быть выделена кавычками, чтобы она распознавалась как строка, а не как имя переменной:

```html
<a href="#" onclick="this.innerHTML = 'текст'"> Контакты</a>
```